# Airflow scheduler does not schedule (or slowly) when lot of tasks

Tags: airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer, airflow

I am working with airflow on Google Cloud Composer (version: composer-1.10.2-airflow-1.10.6).

I realized that my that the scheduler doesn't schedule task when there is a lot of tasks to process (See Gantt view below)

[image: Gantt View]
(don't pay attention to the colours, the red tasks are "createTable Operators" that fail if the table already exists so they have to fail 5 times before the next part (the important one) of the DAG runs)

There are gaps of hours between tasks! (for example 5 hours between 10am and 15pm and nothing happened)

Normally it works fine with ~40 DAGs with about 100-200 tasks each (sometimes a bit more). But recently I added 2 DAGs with a lot of tasks (~5000 each) and the scheduler is very slow or doesn't schedule tasks. 
On the screenshot, I paused the 2 DAGs with a lot of tasks at 15pm and the scheduler is back again, doing its work fine.

**Do you have any solution about it?**

Airflow is meant to be a tool that handle an "infinite" amount of tasks.

*Here are some information about my environment:*

- version: composer-1.10.2-airflow-1.10.6
- cluster size: 6 (12vCPUs, 96GB of memory)

*Here are some information about airflow configuration:*

```
╔════════════════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ Airflow parameter              ║ value ║
╠════════════════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ -(celery)-                     ║       ║
║ worker_concurrency             ║ 32    ║
║ -(webserver)-                  ║       ║
║ default_dag_run_display_number ║ 2     ║
║ workers                        ║ 2     ║
║ worker_refresh_interval        ║ 60    ║
║ -(core)-                       ║       ║
║ max_active_runs_per_dag        ║ 1     ║
║ dagbag_import_timeout          ║ 600   ║
║ parallelism                    ║ 200   ║
║ min_file_process_interval      ║ 60    ║
║ -(scheduler)-                  ║       ║
║ processor_poll_interval        ║ 5     ║
║ max_threads                    ║ 2     ║
╚════════════════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

Thank you for your help

**EDIT:**

26 of my DAGs are created by a single .py file by parsing a huge JSON variable to create all the DAGs and tasks.

Maybe the problem comes from this because today Airflow is scheduling tasks from others DAGs than the 26 (especially the 2 big DAGs) I described.
More precisely, Airflow is sometimes scheduling the tasks of my 26 DAGs but it schedules much more easily and more often the tasks of the other DAGs.

Comment: How is your cluster's health? Did you notice some problem in the memory, processing?

Comment: My cluster seems to be healthy. I didn't notice anything weird.

Comment: Can you check the quotas for your project? https://cloud.google.com/composer/quotas

Comment: Everything is fine with the quotas. And I don't think that the problem comes from this because tothing (at all!) is scheduled for a long period.

Answer (score 4):

High inter-task latency is usually an indicator that there is a scheduler-related bottleneck (as opposed to something worker-related). Even when running the same DAGs over and over again, it's still possible for a Composer environment to suffer from performance bottlenecks like this, because work can be distributed differently each time, or there may be different processes running in the background.

To start, I would recommend increasing the number of threads available to the scheduler (`scheduler.max_threads`), and then ensuring that your scheduler is not consuming all CPU of the node it resides on. You can check CPU metrics for the node the scheduler resides on by identifying where it is, then checking in the Cloud Console. To find the node name:

```
# Obtain the Composer namespace name
kubectl get namespaces | grep composer

# Check for the scheduler
kubectl get pods -n $NAMESPACE -o wide | grep scheduler
```

If the above doesn't help, then it's also possible that the scheduler is intentionally blocking on a condition. To inspect all the conditions that are evaluated when the scheduler is checking for tasks to run, set `core.logging_level=DEBUG`. In the scheduler logs (which you can filter for in Cloud Logging), you can then check all the conditions that passed or failed in order for a task to run or to stay queued.

Comment: The CPU usage seems to be good too. And I changed several times the max_threads of the scheduler but it didn't do anything I believe. For now, I have 4 threads since I have 2 virtual cores in my node.
One more thing. I have 26 DAGs dynamically generated by a single .py file. I splitted this into 26 .py file (so 1 DAG per file) and the scheduler seems to respond better

Answer (score 2):

I feel you should [upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading#upgrading_the_version) to Composer version 1.10.4, having the latest patches always helps.

What database are you working with? Having all those failed tasks is highly inadvisable. Can you use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`?

Comment: Ok for the upgrade, it is always better. For the "CREATE TABLE", I understand your point of view and I will certainly change this (but this is not the problem here); I am using the **native** BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator from airflow which is responsible of all these fails.

Comment: If I understand correctly each of the tasks to create a table runs 5 times which is highly wasteful of resources. I know it's not the exact issue in this case but removing these 4 tasks for each table will result in a lot less tasks. As you are dealing with multiple DAGs all running tasks at the same time it will help, even if there will probably be another step to take after this. I would advise you to add `retries=0` to these tasks or recreate the tasks using the default BigQueryOperator by writing the full `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...` command, time-consuming but it might be worthwhile.

Comment: I totally understand no worries. Some precisions:

- I don't understand why the native BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator operator doesn't handle this but anyway

- retries=0 will break the DAG if the task fails without creating the table the first time.
But yes I agree with you. Anyway this is not the topic here :)

Comment: I agree this is not the topic but trying to solve the topic without addressing the multiple unneeded tasks is also not the best way forward. And yes, you're right, the BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator should be able to handle this natively!

Comment: Following your advices, I changed the the annoying failing tasks! This is indeed better

Comment: What is better? Has the long delay between tasks in the same DAG reduced?

Comment: No, the CreateTable tasks are no more failing for no reason, so this is faster.
For the scheduler issue, I increased the threads to max_threads=4 and I splitted in 26 .py files my 26 DAGs that were generated with a single .py file before. The scheduler works visibly better now